# Keyboard not resigning when i tap the return key (xcode)

Tags: ios

I am trying to get the keyboard to go away, when I press the return key on my application heres my code from the .m:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;

}
```

and the code in the .h:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField* )textField;
```

But when I run the application and hit the return key nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
@interface ChemicalInfoViewController: UIViewController{
IBOutlet UIScrollView *ChemicalInforScroller;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PPMForChlTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *GallonsForChlTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PPMForAlkTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *GallonsForAlkTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PPMForPHTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *GallonsForPHTextField;
- (IBAction)SumbitCDI:(UIButton *)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *PPMLabelForChl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *GallonsLabelForChl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *PPMLabelForAlk;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *GallonsLabelForAlk;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *PPMLabelForPH;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *GallonsLabelForPH;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *ChlorinePoundsTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *GallonsForAlkDecreaser;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PhPoundsTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *AlkPoundsTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *LbsForAlkDecreaser;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PPMForAlkDecreaser;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *LbsForPhDecreaser;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PPMForPhDecreaser;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *GallonsForPhDecreaser;
- (IBAction) clickedBackground;
@interface ChemicalInfoViewController : UIView <UITextField>
@end
```

and my .m:

```
#import "ChemicalInfoViewController.h"

@interface ChemicalInfoViewController ()

@end

@implementation ChemicalInfoViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}





- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[ChemicalInforScroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[ChemicalInforScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
self.textField.delegate = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}


- (IBAction) clickedBackground {

[self.view endEditing:YES];

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `.h`, remove:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField* )textField;
```

And it will work as it should, given that in your `.h`, you conform to the protocol:

```
@interface yourViewController : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

And set up the delegate like so:

```
yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

Edit regarding to the `@end`:

In your `.m`, add a `@end` to the bottom; so , it becomes (*scroll to the very bottom*):

```
@implementation ChemicalInfoViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[ChemicalInforScroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[ChemicalInforScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
self.textField.delegate = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}


- (IBAction) clickedBackground {

[self.view endEditing:YES];

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;

}

@end //Here :-)
```

Comment: that way still didn't work thank you though, any other thoughts?

Comment: @Jake I just tested it. It worked for me. yourTextField is _your text field_; if you have a textField called "textField", then replace that with that.

Comment: must be something wrong with my configuration, im not sure though what else should i check?

Comment: @Jake Remove the method from .h; conform to the protocol as mentioned in answer, then this method should get called and the keyboard gets resigned.

Comment: now it's saying im missing an @end when i already have one haha thank you for your help what could be the issue now?

Comment: @Jake Where does it say that? in .h or in .m? Show your .h file in question please. Usually that happens when a `}` is missing.

Comment: @Jake Here: `@interface ChemicalInfoViewController : UIView <UITextField>
`should be `@interface ChemicalInfoViewController : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate>` and in your .m your are missing a `@end`

Comment: ohh sorry that @end was already there i just forgot to copy it im getting the error in my .h

Comment: okay now im getting a duplicate definition of MyViewControllerClass error

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the delegates for your textfields.

In "viewDidLoad" add

> _ChlorinePoundsTextField.delegate = self;
>
> _GallonsForAlkDecreaser.delegate = self;
>
> _PhPoundsTextField.delegate = self;
>
> _AlkPoundsTextField.delegate = self;
>
> _LbsForAlkDecreaser.delegate = self;
>
> _PPMForAlkDecreaser.delegate = self;
>
> _LbsForPhDecreaser.delegate = self;
>
> _PPMForPhDecreaser.delegate = self;
>
> _GallonsForPhDecreaser.delegate = self;

Answer (score 0):

none of these methods seemed to be working for some reason but what i did end up doing was creating a DidEndOnExit action and resigned the keyboard under that action for each textfield